# how to find area coordinates of a invoice table in pdf file using python?

Tags: python, extract, invoice, tabula, python-camelot

how to find area coordinates of a invoice table in pdf file using python ?
I am currently using camelot or tabula for table extraction from pdf files. However i would like to know if there is way to extract area coordinates of each tables so that i can customise accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In Camelot, table coordinates are specificied in table attribute `_bbox`.

Example:

```
import camelot

tables=camelot.read_pdf('your_doc.pdf', pages='1-end')

for i,table in enumerate(tables):
    print(f'table id: {i}')
    print(f'page: {table.page}')
    print(f'coordinates: {table._bbox}')
```